# Let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Show that $f^2$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Show that $f^2$ is also continuous on the set $[a,b]$.

Here's what I tried.

**EDIT:**
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and take any $y \in [a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous at $y$, by the Boundedness Theorem, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. That is, there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$. On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous at $y$, by definition of continuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in [a,b]$ with $|x-y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| 
< \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$.
Now, we'll show that $f^2$ is also continuous at $y$. Notice that for given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\delta>0$ such that for any $x \in [a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have
\begin{align*}
|f^2(x) - f^2(y)| &= |f(x) + f(y)| |f(x)-f(y)| \\
&\le (|f(x)| + |f(y)|)|f(x) - f(y)| \\
&< (M+M) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} = \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, since $\varepsilon > 0$ and $y \in [a,b]$ are arbitrary, then $f^2$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Q.E.D.

Does this proof correct? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\epsilon$ you picked for continuity of $f(x)$ isn't a fixed number (it depends on $f(x)$ and $f(y)$). However, you can bound $|f(x)|$ on $[a,b]$ by some number $M\geq 0$, since $f$ is continuous on a compact set. Then you can use $M$ to pick your $\delta$ and so that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac \epsilon {2M}$, and the proof should follow similarly.

Comment: @krewlpt To add more, we have to use the fact that a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is bounded and attains its bounds. So that your $\frac{\varepsilon}{|f(x)| + |f(y)|}$ is a fixed number.

Comment: Thanks for the correction sir. I have edit my post. What about now ?

Comment: @krewlpt Yes, that looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Given $\varepsilon>0$ and given $y\in[a,b]$, you have no way of knowing that there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-y|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon{|f(x)|+|f(y)|},$$since $\frac\varepsilon{|f(x)|+|f(y)|}$ is not a fixed number (it depends upon $x$).

You can say that $f^2$ is continuous, since it is equal to $f\times f$ and since the product of two continuous functions is continuous.